# How to use port forwarding to connect to docker container using DNS name

Tags: dns, docker, port, portforwarding

I have 2 redis containers running on same machine m1.

container1 has port mapping 6379 to 6400

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6400 myredisimage1
```

container2 has port mapping 6379 to 7500

```
docker run -d -p 6379:7500 myredisimage2
```

I am looking for a solution where other machine m2 can communicate to machine m1, using different DNS names but same port number.

```
redis.container1.com:6379
redis.container2.com:6379
```

and I would like to redirect that request to proper containers inside machine m1.

Is this possible to achieve this ?

Comment: It may be best to link the containers you are trying to communicate from to these containers. Then you talk to the internal port directly with the DNS name published in your hosts file.

Why can you not listen the process on port 6379?

Comment: ya i had missed this. i think i will go with linking containers.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but hacky. First, ask yourself if you really need to do this, or if you can get away with just using different ports for the containers. Anyway, if you do absolutely need to do this, here's how:

Each docker container gets its own ip address accessible from the host machine. AFAIK, these are generated pseudo-randomly at run-time, but they are accessible by doing a `docker inspect $CONTAINER_ID`, for example:

```
docker inspect e804af2472ca
[
{
    "Id": "e804af2472ca605dec0035f45d3bd05c1fbccee31e6c09381b0c16657378932f",
    "Created": "2016-02-02T21:34:12.49059198Z",
    ...
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        **"IPAddress": "172.17.0.6"**,
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        ...
    }
}
]
```

In this case, we know this container's ip address accessible from the host is 172.17.0.1. That ip address is fully usable from the host, so you can have something proxy `redis.container1.com` to it and `redis.container2.com` to your other ip. You'd need to reload the proxy address every time the box goes up, so this would definitely not be ideal, but it should work.

Again, my recommendation overall is don't do this.

Comment: thanks. I think I will go with what Marcus suggested to link the containers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm getting you right. 
But how could you start two container with both working on the same port?

It seems to me that this should be dealt with by using load balancer. Try HAProxy and set up two acl's for each domain name.

I would go with something like this: (Using docker-compose)

Docker Copose setup to deploy docker images:

```
redis-1:
    container_name: redis-1
    image: myredis
    restart: always
    expose: 
        - "6400"

redis-2:
    container_name: redis-2
    image: myredis
    restart: always
    expose: 
        - "6400"

haproxy:
    container_name: haproxy
    image: million12/haproxy
    restart: always
    command: -n 500
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"
    links:
        - redis-1:redis.server.one
        - redis-2:redis.server.two
    volumes:
        - /path/to/my/haproxy.cfg:/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

And then custom haproxy config:

```
    global
      chroot /var/lib/haproxy
      user haproxy
      group haproxy
      # Default SSL material locations
      ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
      crt-base /etc/ssl/private
      # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
      ssl-default-bind-ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:AES128+EDH:EECDH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!DES:!3DES:!RC4
      spread-checks 4
      tune.maxrewrite 1024
      tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    defaults
      mode    http
      balance roundrobin
      option  dontlognull
      option  dontlog-normal
      option  redispatch
      maxconn 5000
      timeout connect 10s
      timeout client  25s
      timeout server  25s
      timeout queue   30s
      timeout http-request 10s
      timeout http-keep-alive 30s
      # Stats
      stats enable
      stats refresh 30s
      stats hide-version
    frontend http-in
      bind *:6379
      mode tcp
      acl is_redis1 hdr_end(host) -i redis.server.one
      acl is_redis2 hdr_end(host) -i redis.server.two
      use_backend redis1 if is_redis1
      use_backend redis2 if is_redis2
      default_backend redis1 

    backend redis1
      server r1 redis.server.one:6379

    backend redi2 
      server r2 redis.server.two:6379
```